# How Do I Add Sorting To My Custom JPA Interface?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have added a custom interface to my Spring JpaRespository to do some querying that can't easily be done with the generated methods.
e.g. a simplified version:

```
public class DogRepositoryCustomImpl implements DogRepositoryCustom {
  @Autowired
  EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<DogEntity> findDogsByCriteria(String colour, String breed, String name) {
    //Create a root query to build on
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DogEntity> query = builder.createQuery(DogEntity.class);
    Root<DogEntity> root = query.from(DogEntity.class);

    //Add predicates (where clauses) if the parameters are not empty
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(colour)) {
      predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("colour"), colour));
    }
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(breed)) {
      predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("breed"), breed));
    }
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
      predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("name"), name));
    }

    query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
  }  
}
```

I now want to add the option of sorting asc/desc on any of the parameters, but only one at a time.
I also want to have a default sort of asc on colour.

The next step is to add `query.orderBy(....)` to the criteria but I am not sure how best to define the interface for the sorting and how to use it in the criteria query.

If I added a parameter to the interface `Sort sort` I could pass `new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "colour")` or alternatively I could add an enum for the asc/desc and a String for the field to sort on.

Even after deciding that, I'm still not sure how I would create the `Order` to pass into the `query.orderBy(....)`.

How do I define sorting in my interface and how do I implement it?

Comment: Why not use `JpaSpecificationExecutor`? You'll get out-of-the-box support for `Pageable`, and that includes sorting

Answer (score 0):

You split the path in a `Sort` by `.`, and for every part call `Path.get()` starting at `Root<DogEntity>`. The result of that is passed to `asc`/`desc` and added to a list of orders.